whatsapp-web.js setup: npm WARN deprecated puppeteer@13.7.0: < 21.8.0 is no longer supported
I have been working with whatsapp-web.js for a while. It's suddenly stopped and when I tried to re-install it I got these errors:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
npm install whatsapp-web.js

npm WARN deprecated puppeteer@13.7.0: < 21.8.0 is no longer supported
[            ......] / build:fs-extra: sill linkStuff fs-extra@10.1.0 has C:\Users\eng.ghadyalhamad\Desktop\test\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules as i
> puppeteer@13.7.0 install C:\Users\eng.ghadyalhamad\Desktop\test\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer
> node install.js

ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r982053! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: npm.taobao.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.tbcdn.cn, DNS:*.taobao.com, DNS:*.alicdn.com, DNS:*.cmos.greencompute.org, DNS:cmos.greencompute.org, DNS:m.intl.taobao.com, DNS:*.mobgslb.tbcache.com, DNS:*.alikunlun.com, DNS:alikunlun.com, DNS:*.django.t.taobao.com, DNS:alicdn.com, DNS:*.tbcache.com, DNS:*.tmall.com, DNS:*.1688.com, DNS:*.3c.tmall.com, DNS:*.alibaba.com, DNS:*.aliexpress.com, DNS:*.aliqin.tmall.com, DNS:*.alitrip.com, DNS:*.aliyun.com, DNS:*.cainiao.com, DNS:*.cainiao.com.cn, DNS:*.chi.taobao.com, DNS:*.chi.tmall.com, DNS:*.china.taobao.com, DNS:*.dingtalk.com, DNS:*.etao.com, DNS:*.feizhu.cn, DNS:*.feizhu.com, DNS:*.fliggy.com, DNS:*.fliggy.hk, DNS:*.food.tmall.com, DNS:*.jia.taobao.com, DNS:*.jia.tmall.com, DNS:*.ju.taobao.com, DNS:*.juhuasuan.com, DNS:*.lw.aliimg.com, DNS:*.m.1688.com, DNS:*.m.alibaba.com, DNS:*.m.alitrip.com, DNS:*.m.cainiao.com, DNS:*.m.etao.com, DNS:*.m.taobao.com, DNS:*.m.taopiaopiao.com, DNS:*.m.tmall.com, DNS:*.m.tmall.hk, DNS:*.mei.com, DNS:*.taopiaopiao.com, DNS:*.tmall.hk, DNS:*.trip.taobao.com, DNS:*.xiami.com, DNS:1688.com, DNS:alibaba.com, DNS:aliexpress.com, DNS:alitrip.com, DNS:aliyun.com, DNS:cainiao.com, DNS:cainiao.com.cn, DNS:dingtalk.com, DNS:etao.com, DNS:feizhu.cn, DNS:feizhu.com, DNS:fliggy.com, DNS:fliggy.hk, DNS:juhuasuan.com, DNS:mei.com, DNS:taobao.com, DNS:taopiaopiao.com, DNS:tmall.hk, DNS:xiami.com, DNS:tmall.com, DNS:*.cloudvideocdn.taobao.com, DNS:cloudvideocdn.taobao.com, DNS:tbcdn.cn
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:347:12)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1525:27)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:709:12) {
  reason: "Host: npm.taobao.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.tbcdn.cn, DNS:*.taobao.com, DNS:*.alicdn.com, DNS:*.cmos.greencompute.org, DNS:cmos.greencompute.org, DNS:m.intl.taobao.com, DNS:*.mobgslb.tbcache.com, DNS:*.alikunlun.com, DNS:alikunlun.com, DNS:*.django.t.taobao.com, DNS:alicdn.com, DNS:*.tbcache.com, DNS:*.tmall.com, DNS:*.1688.com, DNS:*.3c.tmall.com, DNS:*.alibaba.com, DNS:*.aliexpress.com, DNS:*.aliqin.tmall.com, DNS:*.alitrip.com, DNS:*.aliyun.com, DNS:*.cainiao.com, DNS:*.cainiao.com.cn, DNS:*.chi.taobao.com, DNS:*.chi.tmall.com, DNS:*.china.taobao.com, DNS:*.dingtalk.com, DNS:*.etao.com, DNS:*.feizhu.cn, DNS:*.feizhu.com, DNS:*.fliggy.com, DNS:*.fliggy.hk, DNS:*.food.tmall.com, DNS:*.jia.taobao.com, DNS:*.jia.tmall.com, DNS:*.ju.taobao.com, DNS:*.juhuasuan.com, DNS:*.lw.aliimg.com, DNS:*.m.1688.com, DNS:*.m.alibaba.com, DNS:*.m.alitrip.com, DNS:*.m.cainiao.com, DNS:*.m.etao.com, DNS:*.m.taobao.com, DNS:*.m.taopiaopiao.com, DNS:*.m.tmall.com, DNS:*.m.tmall.hk, DNS:*.mei.com, DNS:*.taopiaopiao.com, DNS:*.tmall.hk, DNS:*.trip.taobao.com, DNS:*.xiami.com, DNS:1688.com, DNS:alibaba.com, DNS:aliexpress.com, DNS:alitrip.com, DNS:aliyun.com, DNS:cainiao.com, DNS:cainiao.com.cn, DNS:dingtalk.com, DNS:etao.com, DNS:feizhu.cn, DNS:feizhu.com, DNS:fliggy.com, DNS:fliggy.hk, DNS:juhuasuan.com, DNS:mei.com, DNS:taobao.com, DNS:taopiaopiao.com, DNS:tmall.hk, DNS:xiami.com, DNS:tmall.com, DNS:*.cloudvideocdn.taobao.com, DNS:cloudvideocdn.taobao.com, DNS:tbcdn.cn",
  .............

Note that I downgraded npm, but the problem still same.

Please include text as text in the question not as an image of text.

Solved !

I download the whatsapp manually from
github


Install NodeJs Version: node-v18.12.0-x64

